# Timestamp to weekday going wrong

Tags: swift

I made this function:

```
func getDayOfWeek(date: NSDate) -> String? {
    let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let myComponents = myCalendar?.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: date)
    let weekDay = myComponents?.weekday
    println(date)
    return weekNumberToWord(weekDay!)
}
```

To which I give a timestamp as date (`1439460000`, which is the date of today) and it prints: `2046-08-13 10:00:00 +0000`. How is this possible?

This is how I call the function:

```
var day = getDayOfWeek(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timestamp.doubleValue))!
```

In which `getDayOfWeek()` is a switch converting all the numbers to day name as string.

Comment: `2046-08-13 10:00:00 +0000` Is the date of today? – How this is possible? I don’t know; maybe you are a time traveller.

Comment: No the timestamp is the date of today. But it returns 2046 to me instead. If it really is the date of today I might be a time traveller indeed. But I hope that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong initializer:

> `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`
>
> Returns an NSDate object initialized relative the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT by a given number of seconds.

You should use `init(timeIntervalSince1970 seconds: NSTimeInterval)` to initialize a date from a UNIX timestamp (which you are apparently using):

> Returns an NSDate object set to the given number of seconds from the first instant of 1 January 1970, GMT.

```
var day = getDayOfWeek(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp.doubleValue))!
```

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot! I only  `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` because it suggested it since I wasn't using an initializer at all. I'm new to Swift and still figuring things out. Thanks a lot for this!